# Как сгруппировать значения в столбике из таблицы и чтоб группировка шла от большего к меньшему?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
meaned = df.groupby(['Инструментальность']).mean()
```

Но группировка идет от меньшего к большему, а надо наоборот.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не работаю с Pandas вообще, но 5 минут поиска дают что-то вроде `meaned = df.sort_values(by=['Инструментальность'],ascending=False).groupby(['Инструментальность']).mean()` Объединил два метода наугад, но направление понятно. Напечатайте тут или в ответе финальный рабочий вариант. И поясните, в  чем у вас была проблема провести поиск?

Comment: @Сергей Сортировать надо после группировки )  Но умение искать информацию и разбираться у вас похвальное

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо:-) А с 'sort_values' не будет работать? `meaned = df.groupby(['Инструментальность']).mean().sort_values(by=['Инструментальность'],ascending=False)`

Comment: @Сергей Да, вообще будет работать, хотя это и индекс, а не колонка. Я не был уверен, но проверил - так тоже работает

Comment: @CrazyElf, о, отлично, спасибо. Значит, я был близок:-) Я пытаюсь наработать интуитивное понимание логики языка, на определённом этапе оно само начнёт мне решать задачи:-)

Comment: @Сергей Если хотите, можете добавить свой вариант ответа, я ему плюс поставлю )

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо большое, но не буду. Ошибся же всё же:-)

Comment: @Сергей спасибо большое, работает!!!

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо большое, работает!!!

Comment: Дарья, если ответ @CrazyElf был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу (а это так, как понимаю) - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Comment: вопрос должен включать пример исходного кода.

Answer (score 1):

Сортировка - это отдельная операция. Просто добавьте сортировку по индексу (`'Инструментальность'` будет индексом после группировки):

```py
meaned = df.groupby(['Инструментальность']).mean() \
        .sort_index(ascending=False)
```

Другой вариант сортировки через `sort_values` тоже работает, спасибо @Сергей за мысль, я не был уверен, что индекс тоже можно сортировать по названию:

```py
meaned = df.groupby(['Инструментальность']).mean() \
         .sort_values(by=['Инструментальность'],ascending=False)
```